# Manipular planilha com userform carregado (excel vba)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Quando estamos com um `userform` carregado, é possível **alterar/navegar** nas planilhas do `excel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Marque a propriedade `ShowModal` do Userform como `False`, ou altere essa propriedade via VBA quando vc quiser (`Me.ShowModal = False`).

Isso lhe permite manipular a planilha enquanto o Userform está aberto, embora ele ainda se mantenha como janela do topo.

Answer (score 3):

Sim!
Defina a propriedade [`ShowModal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/PT-BR/library/office/gg251819.aspx) para `false`.

[image: ShowModal]